# A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Item

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to do a simple JSON return but I am having issues I have the following below.

```
[HttpGet]
    public JsonResult GetItemsEdit()
    {

        try
        {
           var data = _unitOfWork.Items.GetItems();

            return Json(new
            {
                data
               
            }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
            return Json(ex.Message);
        }

        
    }
```

and this is my ajax call code:

```
 // Gets Items on Dropdown

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/Payments/GetItemsEdit",
            datatype: "application/json",
            
            success: function (data) {
                debugger
                alert("ok");
                $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                    $('#Item').append('<option value="' + value.Id + '">' + value.itemName + '</option>');
                });
            },
            error: function (err) {
                console.log("AJAX error in request: " + JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
            }
        });
```

I get a HTTP 500 with the exception as shown in the title of this question.

Is this a bug or my implementation?

Comment: which json library do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not a bug and actually the problem isn't your implementation. The problem is the structure of the returned model.

You can either convert your model into a different model without the references by hand, eg.

```
var data = _unitOfWork.Items.GetItems().Select(x => new { ... });
```

or depending on the json serializer you use you could turn on ignoring circular references.

sample for Newtonsoft.json

```
services
  .AddMvc()
  .AddJsonOptions(jsonOptions => { jsonOptions.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore; } );
```

Some [more insight](https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2020/03/15/fixing-json-self-referencing-loop-exceptions/) for the System.Text.Json library.

Comment: how can i ignoring circular references by details please

Comment: where write this line in my code please `services
  .AddMvc()
  .AddJsonOptions(jsonOptions => { jsonOptions.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore; } );`

Comment: in your Startup.cs. I am not sure which .net/.net core version you use (and which json serializer).

Comment: i use json version 6 and .net mvc

Comment: sorry, missed that part. My answer was aiming .net core